# convert to floating to date in python

Tags: python

I want to convert floating64 to date, I have the following values

1949 which is 01-01-1949
1949.083 which is 01-02-1949

any ideas how to make this conversion in Python

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What is 01-02-1949?? 2 Jan or 1 Feb?

Comment: So the decimal is number of days elapsed in the year divided by 365?

Comment: Hi Sahil, 01-02-1949 is 01Feb1949. the number of months is increasing by increasing the decimal by 0.083.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the decimal is the fraction of the year that has passed (and in the example given 1949.083 would then correspond to January 31, not Feb 1), you can do the following (this will work for leap years as well):

```
import datetime

fl = 1949.083
year = int(fl)
days_in_year = (datetime.datetime(year=year+1, month=1, day=1) - datetime.datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1)).days
days = int((fl - int(fl))*days_in_year)

d = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def float_year_to_datetime(given_time_in_year):
    given_year = int(given_time_in_year)
    remaining_time = given_time_in_year - given_year

    base = datetime(given_year, 1, 1)
    result = base + timedelta(seconds=(base.replace(year=base.year + 1) - base).total_seconds() * remaining_time)

    # Rounding off to days
    result = result.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    result = result + timedelta(days=1)
    return result
```

Results -

```
    float_year_to_datetime(1949.083)
    # datetime.datetime(1949, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```